# Google Cloud Dataprep: Transformation engine unavailable due to prior crash (exit code: -1)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

I am trying to create a flow using Google Cloud Dataprep. The flow takes a data set from Big Query which contains app events data from Firebase Analytics to flatten event parameters for easier analysis. I keep getting the following error before even being able to create the first step (recipe):

> Transformation engine unavailable due to prior crash (exit code: -1)

See top right corner in the screenshot below

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi4sF.png)

Comment: Can you show the tutorial you followed or your detailed steps taken to encounter this issue?

Comment: Did u got the solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

> The error message you received is particularly challenging in that it
>   is so generic. The root cause could be within the platform, or it
>   could be in whatever execution environment you used for the job.
>   Unfortunately, we don't have the resources right now to capture and
>   document all of the error messages that can be emitted during the job
>   execution process, which can span a wide variety of servers and other
>   software platforms.

I encountered the same problem. First I tried following steps:

- Refresh the browser (i.e., click the Reload button top left)
- "Hard refresh" the browser (i.e., ctrl + Reload)
- Clear cache + cookies (i.e., https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/9098093?co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop&hl=en&visit_id=636802035537591679-2642248633&rd=1)

References:

- https://community.trifacta.com/s/question/0D51L00005dG3MXSA0/i-was-working-on-a-recipe-and-i-received-the-error-message-transformation-engine-unavailable-due-x-to-prior-crash-exit-code-1-why-am-i-getting-this-error
- https://community.trifacta.com/s/question/0D51L00005choIbSAI/unable-to-develop-on-our-trifacta-42-platform-for-the-past-12-hours-steps-added-to-recipes-are-lost-and-having-to-recode-the-error-given-is-transformation-engine-unavailable-what-is-causing-this-error

However this did not solve the problem. Then I tried:

- Confirm that your Chrome version is 68+. If not, please upgrade.
- Navigate to chrome://nacl/ and ensure that PNaCl is enabled.
- Navigate to chrome://components/ and ensure that the PNaCl Version is not 0.0.0.0. Click on Check for Updates

Did not solve the problem either.

References:

- https://community.trifacta.com/s/question/0D51L00005dDrcmSAC/not-able-to-preview-data-sources-or-edit-recipes

I got the info from Trifacta, that there has been an internal issue after maintenance. So if non of the above solutions work, you just have to wait and see when they fix the problem.